# Fixing auto-increment ID in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

Hey I was wondering how I could fix my auto increment ID... it seems that everytime I add a row to the table, the ID is 1 off. So here's an example.

My table currently looks like this:

[image: MySQL Table]

Now, as you can see, the last element jumps from 198 to 200. I want this one to be 199.
So say I manually change that last value(200) to 199, it will obviously work, but the next time my script adds a row to the table, it will be on off again(201). Any idea how I could fix it? Thanks for any help, sh042067.

Comment: It's not always a good idea to "reindex" the rows due to joins, if you reindex values, the joins will appear wrongly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jim's right that you should find out the root cause of the 'missing' id.

But if you really just want to re-set the auto-increment counter, you can do this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table AUTO_INCREMENT=200;
```

That should make the next auto-increment id value 200. (Assuming it's MySQL)

Comment: Amazing, I was wondering the same thing....I was almost about to RE MAKE all my table, adding mannualy every article

Answer (score 0):

This probably happened because you removed a row from your table and then added a new row afterward. Is there a reason that you need syncrosy for this table in your id column? Are you planning on removing, replacing, and/or adding new rows. If so, this column will not remain in sync and you'll find that whatever steps you take to fix this problem (could be as easy as dropping the column and recreating it) will need to be done as often as you are removing and adding data.

In short, we need more information about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Now there will not be any dropping of rows. In the begging, yes, I was dropping rows and that must have been the reason of why it is messed up now. But yeah, again, no I will not be removing any rows anymore. Sorry for the lack of information.